# "nosink" in AST nodes

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, raku

This comes from [this issue in the Perl 6 documentation](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2536), on the differential treatment of colonpairs; while `:a` is equivalent to `a => True`, `(:a:b)` is `(a => True b => 1)` and `:a:b` or `:a :b` simply drops the second; colonpairs behave in a different way depending on where they are in the second or first position.
So I have looked at the QAST, which prints this:

```
  - QAST::Block(:cuid(2))  :in_stmt_mod<?> #!/usr/bin/env perl6\n\nuse v6;\n\nsay (:a:b);\n
      - QAST::Var(local __args__ :decl(param)) 
      - QAST::Stmts  #!/usr/bin/env perl6\n\nuse v6;\n\nsay (:a:b);\n
      - QAST::Op(call) 
        - QAST::Block(:cuid(1) :blocktype(declaration_static))  :outer<?> :in_stmt_mod<?> :code_object<?> :IN_DECL<mainline>
          - QAST::Stmts  #!/usr/bin/env perl6\n\nuse v6;\n\nsay (:a:b);\n
            - QAST::Var(lexical $¢ :decl(contvar)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical $! :decl(contvar)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical $/ :decl(contvar)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical $_ :decl(contvar)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical GLOBALish :decl(static)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical EXPORT :decl(static)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical $?PACKAGE :decl(static)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical ::?PACKAGE :decl(static)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical $=finish :decl(static)) 
            - QAST::Var(lexical $=pod :decl(static)) 
              [value]
                - 
            - QAST::Var(lexical !UNIT_MARKER :decl(static)) 
          - QAST::Stmts 
            - QAST::Op(bind) 
              - QAST::Var(local ctxsave :decl(var)) 
              - QAST::Var(contextual $*CTXSAVE) 
            - QAST::Op(unless) 
              - QAST::Op(isnull) 
                - QAST::Var(local ctxsave) 
              - QAST::Op(if) 
                - QAST::Op(can) 
                  - QAST::Var(local ctxsave) 
                  - QAST::SVal(ctxsave) 
                - QAST::Op(callmethod ctxsave) 
                  - QAST::Var(local ctxsave) 
          - QAST::Stmts 
            - QAST::WVal(Array) 
            - QAST::Stmts <sunk> ;\n\nsay (:a:b);\n
              - QAST::Stmt <sunk final> say (:a:b)
                - QAST::Want <sunk>
                  - QAST::Op(call &say) <sunk> :statement_id<2> say (:a:b)
                    - QAST::Stmts <wanted> (:a:b)
                      - QAST::Op(call &infix:<,>) 
                        - QAST::Op(callmethod new) <wanted> :a
                          - QAST::Var(lexical Pair) <wanted> :a
                          - QAST::Want <wanted>
                            - QAST::WVal(Str) 
                            - Ss
                            - QAST::SVal(a) 
                          - QAST::Op(hllbool) <wanted>
                            - QAST::IVal(1) 
                        - QAST::Op(callmethod new) <wanted nosink> :b
                          - QAST::Var(lexical Pair) <wanted> :b
                          - QAST::Want <wanted>
                            - QAST::WVal(Str) 
                            - Ss
                            - QAST::SVal(b) 
                          - QAST::Want <wanted>
                            - QAST::IVal(1) 
                  - v
                  - QAST::Op(p6sink) 
                    - QAST::Op(call &say) <sunk> :statement_id<2> say (:a:b)
                      - QAST::Stmts <wanted> (:a:b)
                        - QAST::Op(call &infix:<,>) 
                          - QAST::Op(callmethod new) <wanted> :a
                            - QAST::Var(lexical Pair) <wanted> :a
                            - QAST::Want <wanted>
                              - QAST::WVal(Str) 
                              - Ss
                              - QAST::SVal(a) 
                            - QAST::Op(hllbool) <wanted>
                              - QAST::IVal(1) 
                          - QAST::Op(callmethod new) <wanted nosink> :b
                            - QAST::Var(lexical Pair) <wanted> :b
                            - QAST::Want <wanted>
                              - QAST::WVal(Str) 
                              - Ss
                              - QAST::SVal(b) 
                            - QAST::Want <wanted>
                              - QAST::IVal(1) 
            - QAST::WVal(Nil)
```

The main difference is that the first colonpair is `- QAST::Op(callmethod new) <wanted> :a`, while the second is `- QAST::Op(callmethod new) <wanted nosink> :b`, please note the `nosink`. The, I guess, important part is where an implicit operator , is called; this operator sinks the first element. But I wonder why the effect of sinking is making the value in the `Pair` equal to `True`, while not sinking it makes it equal to `1`. Is that intended? Some side effect or something I can't really understand? None of the above?